# Iterate Across Columns in a List of Lists in Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, enumerate

When I attempt iteration across columns in a row, the column does no change within a nested loop:

```
i_rows = 4
i_cols = 3
matrix = [[0 for c in xrange(i_cols)] for r in xrange(i_rows)]

for row, r in enumerate(matrix):
    for col, c in enumerate(r):
        r[c] = 1

print matrix
```

**Observed output**

```
[[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]
```

**Expected output**

```
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
```

I have tried different expressions such as `xrange()` and `len()` and I am considering switching to numpy. I am a bit surprised that a two-dimensional array in Python is not so intuitive as my first impression of the language.

The goal is a two-dimensional array with varying integer values, which I later need to parse to represent 2D graphics on the screen.

How can I iterate across columns in a list of lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to assign the value against the `col`, not `c`

```
for row, r in enumerate(matrix):
    for col, c in enumerate(r):
        r[col] = 1               # Note `col`, not `c`
```

Because the first value returned by `enumerate` will be the index and the second value will be the actual value itself.

Comment: This works! So close... I had tried `row[col]` without success.

Comment: @noumenal Yup, again the same thing :-) first value is the index. So `row[col]` tries to subscript a number. That is why you would have received an error. But, try to use List Comprehension as much as possible.

Comment: I had been looking for the docs on this, but was not aware what the concept was called. It seems very flexible and Pythonic.

Comment: @noumenal Do you mean you were looking for the List Comprehension?

Comment: Yes. The thing that is holding me back from List Comprehension is that I need to heurestically generate and compare each integer with the previous one (`i != i_matrix[r][c-1]`) and the one above (`i != i_matrix[r-1][c]`). I guess `itertools.takewhile()` would be a possible solution, but I don't know how to refer to `i`.

Comment: @noumenal LCs are used to create new lists based on only the current information. If you need past information, you can better write it with normal loops itself. Make sure that the code is readable and easily understandable for the future you ;-)